# Paginated Archives or Loop by Month

Tags: pagination, archives, date-time

I'm trying to figure out a way to do a loop / archive page with posts organized by month. So where each page displays post from 1 month. Then the previous and next links would be labeled February 2011 and April 2011, for example.

I'm thinking it would possibly use the date.php file, but I feel like I may run into problems when paginating from one year to the next...

Anyone have any ideas, or documentation on where to look further?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not very hard to do. If you have currently have paginated date-based archives you can just disable paging when you are in a month overview:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse12983_pre_get_posts' );
function wpse12983_pre_get_posts( &$wp_query )
{
    if ( $wp_query->is_month() ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'nopaging', true );
    }
}
```

You can use `get_month_link()` to get links to the adjacent months. If you want to skip months without posts you can call `get_previous_post()` at the beginning of the loop and `get_next_post()` at the end (or you set the global `$post` variable yourself before you call these functions - they don't accept a post argument). Extract the dates from these posts and pass them to `get_month_link()`.

Comment: how would you use this implementation?

Comment: I tried it like this.It dint work which shows am clearly doing it wrong.Some help please @Jan

Comment: @GotaloveCode: Best if you ask a separate question, with code showing what you have tried. And someone else can take a look, as it has been 5 years since I did any serious PHP work.